# HOW TO filter SubFolders' Files in Finder?

Tags: finder

I have SubFolders inside my ParentFolders and I need to filter just the Files inside all Subfolders like seen below:  (I don't need to filter the Folders, I need to filter the FILES inside the Folders)

[image]

I spent the last 2 hours trying to find a way and I ran out of options.

Anyone can offer some help?

Thanks!

Daniel

Comment: You can‘t do this in Finder (well, you could use tags, but that‘s cumbersome). What so you want to do with the filtered list once you have it (there may be other ways to achieve this)?

Comment: Also, this seems to be related to your other question. What is your ultimate objective here?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @nohillside, as always you are very kind. So, I have ParentFolders containing certain Topics (chapters from books). Inside each ParentFolders, I have 5 folders (one of them is a folder called "3_Finished", which is my summary from the chapter). Inside this Folder "3_Finished" I have many files, each from a page of the chapter. I need to see ALL my files together so I can properly TAG them by section of the book, otherwise, I would need to open one "3_Finished" by "3_Finished" and TAG each file individually. Did I make myself clear?

Comment: Much clearer :-) There are command line tools to support this, it might be easier to get good answers if your question focuses on your goal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @nohillside. May I ask where I can find these command lines or if you happen to know them to write them here?

Comment: Please *edit* your question to be specific about what you want to accomplish (mass-update a set of files with a tag), including an explanation on how these files can be identified (by name/pattern, relative position to a parent directory etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a reasonably simple way to do this manually.

Open one folder above the the topmost folder in List View.
Opt/click the reveal arrow of your work folder. This will open the *entire* hierarchy.
Scroll to the bottom of the contents.
Shift-click the last item. This will select everything in that hierarchy.
Right click any of the selected items - add your tag.

[image]

Then open a new Finder Window.
Select your tag in the sidebar.
Press  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>J</kbd>  and Group by Kind.
This will sort the folders to the top.
Shift/select all the folders.
Right click & remove the tag.

[image]

Of course, whilst you're in this view you can add any other tags you wish & re-filter on those later.

Comment: Daniel - sorry, I'd missed a step, now added to answer. I've also clarified a couple of the steps. If either of these answers has helped you, please upvote or mark as 'accepted' as appropriate. This will help future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

### Alternate Solution

I would use **Terminal** with the `find` *command* in conjunction with the *third-party utility* [tag](https://github.com/jdberry/tag/) to *find* and *tag* the target *files*, as IMO this would would be the easiest way to do it.

Assuming all the **Parent Folders** are themselves within a *folder*, e.g. **Parent of Parent Folders**, then the following *example* **shell script** *code* will do as you want:

```
find '/path/to/parent_of_parent_folders' -type f -regex '.*/target_folder_name/.*' -exec echo '/path/to/tag' -a 'Finalizado' {} \;
```

- Note that the *example* **shell script** *code* has an `echo` *command* in it for testing. Run it with the `echo` *command* to see that the *files* that `tag` will be executed on are the correct ones. If it looks right, remove the `echo` *command* and run again to actually *tag* them.
- The `'/path/to/parent_of_parent_folders'` is the *fully qualified POSIX pathname* of the *folder* the e.g. **ParentFolder1** and **ParentFolder2** shown in your drawing. example: `'/Users/Daniel4321/Documents/My Book'`
- `target_folder_name` in `.*/target_folder_name/.*'` would be **Sub Folder 2** in your drawing, or "3_Finished" from your comments.
- `'/path/to/tag'` is the *fully qualified POSIX pathname* of the `tag` *executable* if not placed within the `PATH` passed to the *shell* in **Terminal**. On my system I installed it to `/usr/local/bin/tag` and in **Terminal** only needed to use it as `tag`, omitting the `/path/to/` portion in the *example* **shell script** *code*.

Note that the *example* **shell script** *code* was tested in **Terminal** with actual *paths* and *target folder name* under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue<sup>1</sup>.

- <sup>1</sup>  <sub>Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed.</sub>

**The 'Finalizado'<sup>1</sup> *tag* was added to the target *files*.**

<sub><sup>1</sup>The 'Finalizado' *tag* was taken from your other question: [How to TAG all Files inside hundreds of Folders](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429105/how-to-tag-all-files-inside-hundreds-of-folders)</sub>