# How to TAG all Files inside hundreds of Folders

Tags: finder, automator

Need to TAG all Files inside hundreds of Folders with the same TAG.

TAGName = Finalizado

Is there a way to right-click on these hundreds of Folders and choose a Quick Action to do so?

Thank you.

Comment: I would use **Terminal** with the `find` _command_ in conjunction with the _third-party utility_ [tag](https://github.com/jdberry/tag/) to _find_ and _tag_ the target _files_, as IMO this would would be the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Assuming all the **Parent Folders** are themselves within a _folder_, e.g. **Parent of Parent Folders**, then the following _example_ **shell script** _code_ will do as you want: `find '/path/to/parent_of_parent_folders' -type f -regex '.*/target_folder_name/.*' -exec echo '/path/to/tag' -a 'Finalizado' {} \;` Note that the _example_ **shell script** _code_ has an `echo` _command_ in it for testing. Run it with the `echo` _command_ to see that the _files_ that `tag` will be executed on are the correct ones. If it looks right, remove the `echo` _command_  and run again to actually _tag_ them.

Comment: Note that the _example_ **shell script** _code_ was tested in **Terminal** with actual _paths_ and _target folder name_ under **macOS Catalina** with **Language & Region** settings in **System Preferences** set to **English (US) — Primary** and worked for me without issue. Assumes necessary and appropriate settings in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** have been set/addressed as needed. The 'Finalizado' _tag_ was added to the target _files_.